# C# encrypt and decrypt generic List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, encryption, cryptography

I have been using an answer I found to encrypt and decrypt strings

```
 public class Crypto 

 public static string EncryptStringAES(string plainText, string sharedSecret)
```

[Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string)

However, now I wish to encrypt and decrypt generic List

Example:

```
var fileName = @"C:\temp\troublecall.txt";
FileStream s = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
List<TroubleCall> tcs = new List<TroubleCall>();

foreach (var tc in troubleCalls)
{
    tcs.Add(tc);
}

BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();

f.Serialize(s, tcs);
s.Close();
```

So I cannot use the existing method in that crypto class to encrypt a generic list

So It seems that I could try to encrypt in the loop somehow, right?  Is is possible to just encrypt the entire finished List as an object ?

Comment: It looks complicated

Comment: Serialize the list, then encrypt the encoded list. Decrypt and deserialize to retrieve the original. For large lists you may want to serialize and encrypt a stream.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses